# Cannot execute stored proc linked to C routine in DB2

Tags: db2

DB2 version: 9.7.0.6
OS: RHEL 5

Here are the steps I took to create and bind a C routine to DB2:

1> Created `myprog.sqC` file
2> Executed `db2 prep myprog.sql bindfile`
3> Executed `db2 bind myprog.bnd`
4> Compiled the C code by executing

```
gcc -I /.../sqllib/include -c -fPIC myprog.C
```

5> Created a shared library i.e. `myprog.dll` by executing

```
 gcc -shared -o myprog.dll myprog.o -L /.../sqllib/lib64 -ldb2
```

6> Copied over the dll file created from Step 5 to `/.../sqllib/function/`. Set the permission 755 on the `myprog.dll` file

7> Created stored proc as follows:

```
create procedure myschema.test_func (IN INT_VAL1 INTEGER, OUT INT_VAL2 INTEGER) SPECIFIC test_func1 DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 0 NO SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC LANGUAGE C FENCED THREADSAFE PARAMETER STYLE SQL EXTERNAL NAME 'myprog!myfunc'
```

8> However, when I run the db2 command line : call myschema.test_func(10, ?), I get the error:

```
SQL0444N  Routine "myschema.test_func" (specific name "test_func") is 
implemented with code in library or path ".../sqllib/function/myprog", 
function "myfunc" which cannot be accessed.  Reason code: "4".  
SQLSTATE=42724
```

I have been looking around for quite some time and frankly, I have given up.

Can anyone please help me out here to debug/understand the reason behind error in Step 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiled shared library is named `myprog.dll`, but you've told it to look for one called myprog in the create procedure call (the `.dll` suffix is a Windows-ism).

Rename it from `myprog.dll` to `myprog`.